# When pass variable from form on HTML return TypeError: delete_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'usr_name'

Tags: python, forms, flask, flask-wtforms

The form in **delete.html** page makes the call to Flask route **delete_user** by `action="{{ url_for('admin.delete_user', usr_name=user.username) }}" method="POST"`.

Terminal display the call **post** as show below passing **usr_name=test1** but then started the errors.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2020 22:31:21] "POST /admin/delete HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2020 22:31:27] "POST /admin/delete_user?usr_name=test1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/db_ClashRoyal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/db_ClashRoyal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/db_ClashRoyal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/db_ClashRoyal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/db_ClashRoyal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/db_ClashRoyal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/db_ClashRoyal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/db_ClashRoyal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/db_ClashRoyal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/db_ClashRoyal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/envs/db_ClashRoyal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 272, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: delete_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'usr_name'
127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2020 22:31:27] "GET /admin/delete_user?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2020 22:31:27] "GET /admin/delete_user?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2020 22:31:27] "GET /admin/delete_user?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2020 22:31:27] "GET /admin/delete_user?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

you can see **delete.html** and **delete_user** flask route below, thanks for your hints and help.

```
================  route.py  ===============

from app import db, User
from flask import flash
from flask_login import login_required

@mod.route('/delete_user', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def delete_user(usr_name):
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=req[usr_name]).first()
    flash( user.username + 'been deleted', success)
    return '<h1>Removed</h1>'

================  deleted.html  ===============

{% extends "admin/admin_template.html" %}

{% block title %}Delete User{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#warning">
  Delete
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="warning" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="warningLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" style="color:red;" id="warningLabel">Do you want to remove {{ user.username }}</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <p>{{user.email}} about to remove</p>
          {% if user.is_admin %}
              <p style="color:red">{{ user.username}} is an administrator user</p>
          {% endif %}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <form action="{{ url_for('admin.delete_user', usr_name=user.username) }}" method="POST">
              <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly passing the **usr_name=user.username** but your route do not accept any such parameter. You need to change your route to something like this:

```
@mod.route('/delete_user/<usr_name>', methods=['POST'])
```

You can optionally pass the type also like:

```
@mod.route('/delete_user/<str:usr_name>', methods=['POST'])
```

For your reference you can go through: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-viii-followers and search for **Integrating Followers with the Application**. I know its not what exactly you are looking for but you might find it useful as to *how arguments are passed from url to views*.

Comment: Thanks, for explanation and link.